# Quick way to integrate Xaml in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, silverlight, xaml

I have a WPF/C# application.
It contains some .XAML pages.

i would like to integrate this application into my ASP.NET/C# web application.

I want the application to show in an asp.net page.

What is the best way to do this?

I heard that I can use Silverlight. 
I never worked with silverlight before. Can I do it without knowing silverlight or should I have a knowledge in silverlight before doing it?

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either deploy your WPF application as an [XBAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970060.aspx) or migrate it to [Silverlight](http://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/resources/). I'd recommend the latter because you'll get better browser/os support.

Just create a new Silverlight project and copy your xaml files into it. Probably, everything will be compatible since both frameworks have a lot in common. Silverlight is a bit more restrictive since it's a web framework, but it also has other features that WPF doesn't. If you find something that's not compatible, just search for an alternative here.

Comment: Thanks for the tips I will try to migrate to silverlight and if it doesn't work I'll use XBAP